# When iterating cache files using WinInet's methods, how can I skip large files?

Tags: caching, wininet

A part of my program uses WinInet's caching function (e.g. FindFirstUrlCacheEntry, FindNextUrlCacheEntry) to go through the system cache and delete files that meet certain criteria.

The problem is that when a large file is found in the cache, FindNextUrlCacheEntry fails with ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER, and requests an unreasonable buffer size to continue (over 10MB), which I fail to allocate on that system.

I need a way to either:
- Skip large files (somehow get to the next entry)
- Get the cache entry of large files without allocating a large buffer

I noticed the "Retrieve" cache functions, but they all require URLs - and I can't even get the URL of my entry...

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Guypo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was my bug, WinInet doesn't actually attempt to read the full file. 
Still, a way to skip files could have been useful...